# Aligning Content of CommandBar in UWP

Tags: uwp-xaml

How can I align content in the content section of the `CommandBar` horizontally right? Before Anniversary Update, this was still possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Solution

Disable the `IsDynamicOverflowEnabled` property and set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Right`. After doing this, you will get the same behavior as in pre-Anniversary Update SDK versions.

```xml
    <CommandBar HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                IsDynamicOverflowEnabled="False">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Content" />
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
```

[image: Centered content in CommandBar]

## Cause of the issue

With the Anniversary Update SDK (Windows 10 version 1607) a new property was added to the `CommandBar` control - [`IsDynamicOverflowEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.isdynamicoverflowenabled). This property is set to `true` by default and its purpose is to **automatically overflow** the app bar commands from primary area on the bar to the secondary area.

This addition however required a change in the default template of the control. If you look into the default of `CommandBar` template in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic\generic.xaml`, you will see that the template contains a new `VisualStateGroup`:

```xml
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="DynamicOverflowStates">
<VisualState x:Name="DynamicOverflowDisabled"/>
<VisualState x:Name="DynamicOverflowEnabled">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="ContentControlColumnDefinition.Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Target="PrimaryItemsControlColumnDefinition.Width" Value="*"/>
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

By default the control has the `ContentControlColumnDefinition.Width` set to `*` and `PrimaryItemsControlColumnDefinition.Width` set to `Auto`, which means the content will fill all the available space left after putting in the primary commands. This behavior however doesn't make sense for dynamic overflow, because that requires the commands to take as much space as possible before overflowing. Hence, the `VisualState` `DynamicOverflowEnabled` switches the column widths appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.