# CommandBar.Content AppBarButton Label position right

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

this is my code:

```
       <CommandBar DefaultLabelPosition="Right" IsOpen="True">
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Account" Label="Test 1"></AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar.Content>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Test 2"/>
        </CommandBar>
```

and this is the result what I got:
[image]

So now how I trigger that the label are on the right? `DefaultLabelPosition` doesn't effect the content values.

I want to create a toolbar like in WPF or WinForms.

Greetz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning Content of CommandBar in UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126481/aligning-content-of-commandbar-in-uwp)

Comment: where is this a duplicate?

Comment: You just want your buttons to align horizontal right, right?

Comment: No,  I want that the label from the right AppBarButton is right like on the right AppBarButton.

Comment: Ah ok, retracted vote, sorry must have misunderstood intent.

Answer (score 2):

There are few things to note here.

1) `DefaultLabelPosition` can be used in apps targeting Anniversary Update. So if you want to use this for apps targeting previous versions, it would not work.

2) Irrespective of point above, `CommandBar.Content` is by itself a separate presenter with `AppBarButton`.

**How can i get this working?**

You can create a style template from default `AppBarButton` Template and design your `ContentRoot` as required.

Below is the Grid that I changed while playing around sometime before.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Margin="5,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

*Also Style has VisualState `Compact` which hides the label text on AppBar Close so comment this out*

and then assign this style to your buttons.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsOpen="True">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Account" Label="Test 1" Style="{StaticResource RightAlignAppBarButton}"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Accept" Style="{StaticResource RightAlignAppBarButton}" />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

This is the output

[image]

Here is the full style for your reference.

```
<Style x:Key="RightAlignAppBarButton" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="68"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                <Grid x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Name="LabelOnRightStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                            <!--<VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>-->
                            <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="12,14,0,14"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Left"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="8,15,12,17"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="38,0,12,0"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Margin="5,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowTextLabel" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,0,12,0" Padding="0,5,0,7" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" TextTrimming="Clip" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can play around with few other properties and get the output as desired.

Comment: such a big style for such a simple thing? But on the screenshot, you have the "3 dot menu".

Comment: That is controlled by `CommandBar` Itself. If i remember correctly, There should be a `Button` by name `MoreButton` in the default Style for `CommandBar`. All you need to do is Comment out this `Button` in `ContentRoot` and also disable anything that is related to `MoreButton` from `VisualStates`. I don't have access to a Solution to do that now but this should be fairly simple from Blend

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, so I put together two `CommandBars` side by side:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <CommandBar DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
       ... Left aligned AppBarButtons ...
    </CommandBar>

    <CommandBar Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
        ... Right aligned AppBarButtons ...
    </CommandBar>

</Grid>
```

While not perfect, it worked decently for me before and after collapsing:

[image]
[image]